# Calculate maximum of lengths

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations, lengths

How can I calculate a maximum of lengths? I am aware of `pgfmath's` function `max(x_1,x_2,...)`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,draft]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfmathparse{max(3,4)}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

But what if I have lengths instead of numbers?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,draft]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newlength{\foo}
\setlength{\foo}{1cm}

\newlength{\baz}
\setlength{\baz}{1cm}

\pgfmathparse{max(\foo,\baz)}

\newlength{\qux}
\setlength{\qux}{\pgfmathresult}
```

`\pgfmathresult` doesn't have a unit of measurement.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The result is actually a length in points (pt) without the unit. You can simply add this unit again:

```
\setlength{\qux}{\pgfmathresult pt}
```

There is also the `\pgfmathsetlength` macro:

```
\pgfmathsetlength{\qux}{max(\foo,\baz)}
```

Answer (score 12):

I also found a solution with `calc` package:

```
\usepackage{calc}

\setlength{\qux}{\maxof{\foo}{\baz}}
```