# How to get the maximum/minimum of two or more values for variable assignment

Tags: comparison

I want to assign a variable dynamically, based on the maximum of two values. I have seen a `max` function used here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/505352/194783. I cannot see how it is used, though.

Also, I want to know about other options for this and what is the best one to use.

Related questions:

- [Calculate maximum of lengths](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12037/calculate-maximum-of-lengths)

Comment: Is [ipavlic's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12040/411) in the thread you linked to not applicable or unclear? If so, explain why not, and explain a bit more about your use case. Are these "variables" lengths? Or counters? Or something else?

Comment: I want to know the best way. But yes, ideally, that answer would work. Apparently, for my use case, it doesn't (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430402/tikz-pgf-and-maxof-broken-since-3-0-1a).

Also, I didn't really find a good result on Google for this general question that I had. So that is why I created this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the macro `\maxvalue` for example:

```
\def\maxvalue(#1,#2){\ifnum #1>#2 #1\else #2\fi}

\newcount\num
\num=\maxvalue(10,11)

\the\num % prints 11

\bye
```

Comment: When I tried it, it didn't work for me (maybe only for my use case, not sure). A different version of this worked, though.

Comment: @clel Please, be more specific. I.e. show an example where it didn't work.

Comment: I wanted to use this function to assign a style value for a tikzpicture. I just created a MWE, though, to test the general functionality of your approach. In the MWE, it works, so I guess this is related to the usage in the scope of TikZ.

Comment: BTW: Is `\bye` a command that you use, or did you include it just for fun?

Comment: @clel `\bye` is a Plain TeX macro which ends the document. This example is plain TeX but you can include it to a LaTeX document too (without the `\bye`).

Comment: Ah, alright. I am using LaTeX, thus I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: You was asking for "the best one to use". I show the example independent of the used format (i.e. independent of LaTeX macros). This is IMHO "best one to use" because it works in all formats (plain TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt, OpTeX, ...) because it is based only on TeX primitives.

Answer (score 0):

You can exploit the fact that lengths in TeX are always normalized in `pt` and that `l3-fp` converts lengths to their value in points as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\maxlength}{m}
 {
  \fp_eval:n { max(#1) } pt
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newlength{\testlen}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\testlen}{\maxlength{1pt,2pt,3pt}}

\the\testlen

\maxlength{45pt,0.5\textwidth,20cm}---\the\dimexpr20cm\relax

\maxlength{45pt,3\textwidth,20cm}---\the\dimexpr3\textwidth\relax

\edef\test{\maxlength{600pt,\textwidth,6cm}}

\texttt{\meaning\test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As usual, for older versions of LaTeX you might need `\usepackage{xparse}`.